# Which spline function would be best suited for the trajectory of a differential drive

Tags: control, motion-planning

What's the best kind of spline that can be used for generating trajectory that can be adapted during execution time?

The use case is having a differential drive which has to move towards a point (x,y,theta) without stopping during the movement (e.g. no, turn toward the goal, straight move to the goal position, turn to the goal orientation). The robot is provided with a laser scanner for detecting dynamic obstacles which have to be avoided.

What's the best kind of controller in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I have not done it myself yet, but, I have always planned on finding algorithm(s) here;

http://opensteer.sourceforge.net/

The controller they include is called 'unaligned collision avoidance'.